# Zeroth cohomology of manifold with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients

Tags: homology-cohomology, cyclic-groups, group-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Then the zeroth de Rham cohomology
$$H_{\text{dR}}^0(M,\mathbb R)\cong \mathbb R^{\pi_0(M)}$$
counts the number of connected components of $M$. What does the 0-th cohomology $H^0(M,\mathbb Z_n)$ with coefficients in the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_n$ count?

Comment: The same thing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? What types of relevant mathematics are you familiar with, what are your thoughts on the question, etc.? See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960.

Comment: Apologies for being very concise with my question. I'm familiar with de Rham cohomology, but not with (co)homology with different coefficients than $\mathbb R$. For my application it is sufficient to understand the top/bottom (co)homology with say $\mathbb Z_n$ coefficients.